# Localization file is missing

Tags: ios, localization

When I use string localization with a custom table:

```
NSLocalizedString("I'm new user. Register", tableName: "LoginVC", comment: "Registration button")
```

And then export->translate my file->import new language I got multiple files:

[image]

[image]

But when I build my project I receive the following warning:

[image]

This happens for all my tables except the standard `Localizable.strings` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first screenshot shows the `LoginVC.strings (Base)` file missing from version control. Are you sure the file is actually present in your working directory?

For instance, double check the contents of your `Base.lproj` directory. If `LoginVC.strings`is missing try creating it manually.

Comment: After pushed files to git, warning disappeared